# Issues with text-align

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with `text-align = top;` in my CSS. What I want is to have the paragraph element, be aligned at the top, and to the right of my image. It works fine on the first line, but the second line is still beneath my image. I tried also doing horiz-align; but that didn't do it for me.

The W3C page I was looking at is as follows: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

the CSS code is below:

```
img.top {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

And this is the part of the HTML, which I am trying to manipulate.

```
<p>
<img class = top src="../images/myImage.gif" alt="A curious stack question"/>
    Many questions <br/>
    Are most certainly to come
</p>
```

I suspect part of the issue is the `<br/>` as without it the text does get aligned to the top; but I do require the `<br/>` in that location for formatting. I was thinking of using `<pre>`; but I am not sure if that would be the best solution.

Comment: w3schools is most definitely != w3.org. And there is no `horiz-align;`

Comment: Aye, but from what my teacher has mentioned is that it is by the same group. Apologies if mistaken. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try floating the image left instead of setting the text-align

Comment: `class = top` should be `class="top"` is that a typo?

Comment: @SomeStudent Not to further the argument, but I thought I'd help fix the misunderstanding: "The site derives its name from the World Wide Web (W3), but is not affiliated with the W3C" (See http://www.w3schools.com/about/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How tied are you to that structure? You could do this instead:

**HTML:**

```
<img class="top" src="..img/img.jpg"/>
<p>
    Many questions <br/>
    Are most certainly to come
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
img.top {
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/6pwry2nn/

Comment: My partner and I found the solution really quickly after we posted this question, but it is similar in nature in that we have the following property inside of the <img> tag align: left. I will mark your answer as correct as it follows the same logic, many thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes it out dated? is it just not recommended by W3C?